# Raw Soap requests/responses in citrus

Tags: http, soap, citrus-framework

Is there any way to send raw soap requests and responses in Citrus-framework as client or server ? I have a plain text of a soap-request and want to send it to a server. Afterwards I want to validate the plain text/ xml - response.

Regards,
Suspicious Dee

Answer (score 0):

Have you checked this [sample project](https://github.com/citrusframework/citrus-samples/tree/master/samples-soap/sample-soap/java-dsl) ? This is a good example of how to test SOAP endpoints with Citrus. Basically, when you send an XML with a `soap()` action, it will be wrapped inside a SOAP envelope. Citrus handles all the SOAP technical details behind the scenes so you can keep your tests simple.

But it also depends on what you mean by "raw soap requests and responses". If you want to have complete control over the entire XML (SOAP envelope + body) you can use the standard HTTP actions, [documentation](http://citrusframework.org/reference/html/index.html#http-rest-client) & [sample project](https://github.com/citrusframework/citrus-samples/tree/master/samples-http/sample-http/java-dsl). There are some things that you need to know when using this approach:

- you must send the complete SOAP Envelope
- you need to set the correct **Content-Type** HTTP header depending on the SOAP version
- if you are using SOAP 1.1 you also need to send the **SOAPAction** HTTP header
- there is no schema validation

Comment: Yes I first used this project as a template. The first problem was that Citrus could not deal with the wsdl or let's say automatically extract the need xsd, so I did this manually.After this Citrus built the test and even showed a "pass" although it did not execute something nor give a warning. This is because I thought  of sending the soap-request as plain text, as I have some logging information. Currently this is only for prototyping so this might be okay.                            
Anyway, I did not set the content-type nor the SOAPAction as mentioned in your solution. I will giv e a try

Answer (score 0):

By default Citrus will handle the SOAP envelope automatically and wrap/unwrap the payload body for you. In case you want to keep the SOAP envelope as is in order to provide the whole SOAP message by yourself you need to set this on the server endpoint:

```
<citrus-ws:server id="soapServer"
    port="8080"
    auto-start="true"
    keep-soap-envelope="true"/>
```

With `keep-soap-envelope="true"` you can now specify the SOAP envelope by yourself when dealing with messages on this server endpoint. In validation you would now be able to provide the whole SOAP envelope as expected message content.

On the client side you need to use the plain `http-client` component in Citrus as the `soap-client` component is not able to keep the SOAP envelope at the moment.

Using the core http components on client and server side for sending and receiving SOAP messages with SOAP envelope provided by the tester is also possible of course.